# Python Selenium webdriver throws Attribute error

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python selenium webdriver in our framework , of late we have been seeing errors  like below

```
(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, 
AttributeError("'unicode' object has no   attribute 'text'",)
,<traceback     object at 0x00000000037D8D48>)
```

And also we are seeing this error in our product which has unicode charecters in them.Doesnt happen always happens once in 15 times.

Stacktrace:

```
self.compare_units_test('Singapore')
    line 391, in compare_units_test
    self.assertTrue(home_page.is_loaded(), Errors.HOMEPAGE_LOGO_ERROR)
    File "", line 32, in is_loaded
    "Logo did not load results in 10 seconds")
    File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pscore\core\support\ps_wait.py", line 20,in      until_visible
    self._wait_until_visible(locator, timeout, message, True)
    File "venv\lib\site-packages\pscore\core\support\ps_wait.py", line 15, in  _wait_until_visible
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator), message=message)
   File "\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 66, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "\venv\lib\site- packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 72, in  __call__
    return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
   File \venv\lib\site- packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 90, in  _element_if_visible
    return element if element.is_displayed() else False
    AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'

    2015-09-10 15:56:36 - INFO  wd_testcase.py:111 in run : Test Runner: Tearing down test: test_compare_units (tests.test.TestFlightsSearch)
2015-09-10 15:56:36 - INFO  wd_testcase.py:48 in tearDown : Test Runner: Attempting to teardown.
2015-09-10 15:56:36 - ERROR  wd_testcase.py:125 in run : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \venv\lib\site-packages\pscore\core\wd_testcase.py", line 112, in run
    self.tearDown()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pscore\core\wd_testcase.py", line 49, in tearDown
    WebDriverFinalizer.finalize(self.driver, self.has_failed(), self.logger, self.test_context)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pscore\core\finalizers.py", line 28, in finalize
    WebDriverFinalizer.finalize_skygrid(driver, test_failed, test_context)    File "\lib\site-packages\pscore\core\finalizers.py", line 152, in finalize_skygrid
    WebDriverFinalizer.finalise_skygrid_driver_failure(driver, test_context)
    File "\venv\lib\site-packages\pscore\core\finalizers.py", line 168, in    finalise_skygrid_driver_failure
    final_url = driver.current_url
      File "venv\lib\site-   packages\selenium\webdriver\support\event_firing_webdriver.py", line 201, in    __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)AttributeError: current_url
```

We are using 2.45 version of selenium and 2.7.7 version of python.

When i dug into webdriver source code found this

```
try:
str = basestring
except NameError:
pass
```

which specifically addresses the unicode problem which webdriver was running into. 
Any ideas what might be causing this? Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What code are you executing? On which line in your code does it fail?

Comment: Mostly when i try to locate something using ` XPATH `
    self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='browse-data-  entry']/h3)[{}]".format(index)).text

Comment: It doesnt fail always , fails intermittently which is making debugging painful,

Comment: Thanks. What is the value of the "locator" when the test fails?

Comment: Ideally it shoukd return text but sometimes I think it has a unicode value

Comment: Please post the code you are using and point out which line is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause of the problem, it looked like one of the tests was spawning a new browser window and the subsequent tests were using the dialog window instead of the browser window to do selenium commands. At some point one of the tests performed a `driver.quit` and when the subsequent tests tried to access `driver.something` they failed since driver was already killed.